# Pycuda installation on Ubuntu

Tags: python, boost-python, pycuda

I'm having a difficult time installing pycuda. I am running on Ubuntu 12.04. I first installed the Enthought python distribution (even though I already had python on the computer). I added the enthought python location to the path in my .profile (and this works without issue, typing python or ipython from the command line correctly uses the enthought version). I then followed the instructions from http://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Installation/Linux/Ubuntu (skipping steps 0-1 as I already had numpy and cuda installed).

Everything seems to run and install fine. But when I try to actually use pycuda, it fails. For example, here's what happens when I try to run the hello_gpu.py example:

```
:~/Downloads/pycuda-2012.1$ python examples/hello_gpu.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples/hello_gpu.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pycuda.driver as drv
  File "/usr/lib/python_enthought/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycuda-2012.1-py2.7-linux-        x86_64.egg/pycuda/driver.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pycuda._driver import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/libboost_python-py27.so.1.46.1: undefined symbol:         
PyUnicodeUCS4_FromEncodedObject
```

Alternatively, when I try to import the pycuda package from idle, I get a different error:

```
Python 2.7.3 |EPD 7.3-1 (64-bit)| (default, Apr 11 2012, 17:52:16) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)] on linux2
Type "credits", "demo" or "enthought" for more information.
>>> import pycuda
>>> pycuda
<module 'pycuda' from 'pycuda/__init__.pyc'>
>>> import pycuda.driver as drv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pycuda/driver.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pycuda._driver import *
ImportError: No module named _driver
```

I suspect part of the issue is me somewhere not specifying the correct path to the python interpreter, but I cannot figure out where this error occurs. Any suggestions would be most welcome, I am out of ideas.

Comment: If PyCUDA has bugs, you might consider other options like ArrayFire Python which I'm working on.  It is the most extensive GPU library for Python, here:  http://www.accelereyes.com/arrayfire/python/

Comment: Thanks, though since I have a bunch of code already written for pycuda, it would be a shame to switch now...

Comment: @miz: it looks like you have mixed up the Enthought Python distribution and the Ubuntu standard system Python. You can't mix binary libraries built for the system Python with Enthought (which is built with intel's compiler, not gcc). You must either use 100% System or 100% Enthough (the latter probably meaning building your own version of booth-python again Enthought, if that is possible).

Comment: Thanks talonmies - I uninstalled the Enthought package and just went with the system python, and that worked. Was trying to save time by installing the enthought package so I wouldn't have to install all the nice things it comes with by hand (ipython,matplotlib, etc) but in the end it would have been faster to build from scratch. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @talonmies and miz, I usually build PyCUDA against a non-system Python (usually provided by the Sage). The PyCUDA documentation includes comprehensive instructions on how to do this. It should be easy to accommodate those instructions to EPD's Python.

Comment: @miz, http://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Installation/Linux and these were my experiences from a couple of years ago http://markmail.org/message/7mdmxypqjwrfph4e#query:+page:1+mid:5ucnxedz4b7mblx4+state:results

Answer (score 0):

This problem would appear to have been caused by conflicts between two different Python installations on the same system. The OP apparently solved this by uninstalling an Enthough Python installation and using only the system Python installation. There might well be other ways to solve this using a non-system Python installation, as suggested [here](http://markmail.org/message/7mdmxypqjwrfph4e#query:+page:1+mid:5ucnxedz4b7mblx4+state:results)

[This answer was assembled from comments and added as a community wiki entry in the hope it will receive a vote and be removed from the unanswered list for the PyCUDA tag]